# Unity - Moving a ball to the y-coordinates of a Kinect hand, but doesn't show up equally high

Tags: unity-game-engine, kinect, kinect-sdk

I want to move a ball to the same Y-height as the detected right hand position.

I have them on the same distance from the camera, so it's a bit strange, but the ball doesn't go as high as it should go.

I am wondering if I am getting the correct coordinates out of the Kinect API. I noticed there is also a variable Vector3 posRel. But I'm not sure how I can access that.

```
    Vector3 testcoord = manager.GetJointPosition(userId, (int)KinectInterop.JointType.HandRight);

    if (testcoord[1] > MaxHeight){
        MaxHeight = testcoord[1];
        }

    Vector3 ballcoord = Ball.transform.position;
    ballcoord.y = testcoord [1];
    ballcoord.z = testcoord [0];
    Ball.transform.position = ballcoord;
```

Comment: what about MaxHeight?

Comment: I think maybe my script has a sort of conversion from kinect coordinates to avatar coordinates. I am checking..

Comment: using the testcoord directly you have the hand joint position...your are making something wrong in another place